# R: GillespieSSA plot all the runs

Tags: r

I'm using the `GillespieSSA` package for R and I'm running it for 10 runs. The code is as follows:

```
library(GillespieSSA)
init <- c(S=199, I=1)
a <- c("0.03*{S}*{I}","1*{I}")
nu <- matrix(c(-1, +1, +1, -1),nrow=2,byrow=T)
out <- lapply(X=1:10,FUN=function(x) ssa(init, a, nu, tf=10)$data)
plot(out[[3]][,3],type="l",xlab="Time",ylab="I(t)")
```

My question is I can plot a particular run, say the third run, out[[3]] gives the third run of the data, however I wish to plot all the runs to know the frequency of each run. I have no idea how to write the code. I am stuck for weeks and I'm extremely weak in R programme.

Comment: What do you mean by `frequency`? Do you mean the `average`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked in a wrong way just now. My question is in the 10 runs, how can I plot the frequency of each values of the second element, which is I in this model. The graph should be plotted with x-axis is I and y-axis is frequency. Is there a way of plotting it?

Comment: Do you want the distribution for `I` at a particular time point?

Comment: No. No distribution involved. My intention is to know how the graph distributed after plotted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the frequencies for all the runs, is this what you are looking for?

```
par(mfrow=c(4,3))

for (i in seq_along(out)){
  hist(out[[i]][,3],xlab="I(t)", main=paste("Run ", i))
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The OP wants `I` on the x-axis, not time.

Comment: If the frequency is desired, why not just plot a histogram for `out[[i]][,3]` ? I don't understand ``the frequency of each values of the second element` in the OP's comment. Isn't the second element `S` and not `I`?

Comment: Thank you. It did show all the runs. Another question I felt weird is out[[i]][,3] gives the runs of the second element instead of out[[i]][,2]. Is this correct because when I plot out[[i]][,2], it gives the result of the first element.

Comment: I am really weak in R programme. If I did any mistakes, please kindly tell me so. I am confused with my own answers as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Try `head(out[[1]][,1])`, `head(out[[1]][,2])`  and `head(out[[1]][,3])` to see what your data looks like

Comment: It shows errors for the head(out). Does any packages required for this command?

Comment: Yes. The graph should be plotted with x-axis is I and y-axis is frequency. And yes, I need histogram for this. The frequency of each values of element I for the 10 runs.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I now can get what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I want to sum up the frequency of all the runs and plot in a graph?
For example, at I=0, lets say Run1 have 2, Run2 have 4 and so on, I want to sum up and plot the total of frequency at I=0.